# Declaration of wchar_t by myself

Tags: c, linux, declaration, wchar-t

Please tell me, where can I find the wchar_t declaration.
I use linux, and I think it is 32 bits.
I need to declarate this type, because i can't use the standart library (it is used in my boot programm).
The files /usr/include/wchar.h and /usr/include/linux/stddef.h
don't contain the declaration of it.
Also what about mbstate_t?

Comment: "32 bytes" sounds a bit too big for a data type, IMO. ^^

Comment: I'v found the information about mbstate_t - it is structure

Comment: `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: The file stddef.h on my PC was no full

Comment: install a conforming C compiler then. Section 6.4.4.4/11 of C standard specifies that `wchar_t` is defined by `<stddef.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using the standard library, then you do not need `wchar_t`.  Or at least the standard library's idea of `wchar_t` doesn't matter to you.  How could it?  If you want wide character handling then you'll need to write whatever functions are needed for it, and you are free to define and use whatever types are most suitable / convenient for that purpose.

<s>You probably will need the *kernel* headers, though, if you intend make system calls.  I can't imagine how your boot program could avoid that, or why it would want to do.  Those types you would need for that purpose will be defined among the kernel headers.</s>
You will not need kernel headers, either: since the point of your program is to load and start the kernel, it cannot rely on system calls into the kernel to do its job.

The bottom line is that since you have to provide everything not available directly from the hardware / firmware -- which does not present a C interface -- no C definitions outside your own code are relevant to you.  In particular, `wchar_t` is not a characteristic of any system; rather, it is a characteristic of a particular C library.  Different C libraries for the very same system, including yours, can freely define it differently.  If you choose to implement your own wide-character functions, there is no advantage whatever to choosing a `wchar_t` definition drawn from *some other* C library.

Comment: I don't think you can make system calls in a boot program. BIOS calls are possible, but there aren't any header files for these.

Comment: Yes. System calls are not available. I'm writing a boot code and use some standart library functions (I'll implement them).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go to the files containing the definition of wchar_t.
In the standard header `stdint.h` it can be found the information about integer types in your particular implementation.

For example, the constants `WCHAR_MIN` and `WCHAR_MAX` bring information about the range of values of `wchar_t`.

On the ohter hand, if `WCHAR_MIN == 0`, then `wchar_t` is an `unsigned integer type`. Else, it's a `signed integer type` (in this case it would prefirable to check the condition `WCHAR_MIN < 0`).

To know the amount of bytes used to represent a `wchar_t` object, you have, of course, the expression `sizeof(wchar_t)`.